# How to make product attributes appear as checkbox on the add-to-cart form?

Tags: 7, commerce

In Drupal Commerce how to make product attributes appear as checkboxes on the add-to-cart form? I want to see the sum of the prices of all checked products and add them all to the cart, when the add-to-cart submit button is pressed.

I wonder if there is tutorial, or - even better a module - for that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that is feasible. A product attribute is on the product variant, not the product display/node.  The user would need to add multiple product variants to the cart to see the aggregated price.  So they need to choose one, add it to the cart, choose another, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you're asking for is [Commerce Add to Cart Extras](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras).